# Rewrite rules in multisite

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've been trying to set up different rewrite rules on my multisite installation, but as of now, nothing is working. Even the simple

`add_rewrite_rule('^welcome$', 'index.php?p=1', 'top');`

isn't working.

Is there anything to do when setting up rewrite rules using the Rewrite API that needs to be done that isn't explicitity defined in the codex?

This problem led me to wonder: are rewrite rules written using the API supposed to be written in .htaccess or not?

Thank you in advance.

PS. If I'm duplicating, I am sorry, but I haven't been able to find a well written answer yet.

Comment: Yes you have to flush rules after rewriting  you could update the permalinks via admin panel

Comment: I am flushing them. I've tried these three ways: resaving the permalinks in the admin panel, `global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->init(); $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` and `flush_rewrite_rules();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answers:

1. There is nothing to do when using the Rewrite API that isn't written in the Codex.
2. Rules written using `add_rewrite_rule` are not added to `.htaccess`. WP adds them to its database under `rewrite_rules` in the `_options` table.

It's important not to forget to:

- Filter the rewritten permalinks; call the functions on the [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) hook and/or the [`term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_link/) hook depending on the situation.
- Remove default rules to avoid conflict and call the function/s on the [`rewrite_rules_array`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rewrite_rules_array/) hook.
- Flush and rewrite the rules using `flush_rewrite_rules();` on plugin activation and/or deactivation.