# Add slug to default post permalinks ONLY

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've been browsing and reading and testing and can't seem to find a clean solution for my problem. A solution that doesn't affect all other post types, categories, custom taxonomies, etc. :(

Is there anyway to modify the default post permastructure only programmatically by prepending an hardcoded slug to it?

As of now, I've tried using `$wp_rewrite`, `add_permastruct`, `set_permalink_structure`...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332921/custom-permalink-structure-with-a-prefix-just-for-posts)

Comment: Thanks. Just found a simple answer -> gotta hook the function to `post_link`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/

Comment: If you only use the `post_link` filter, you change the links generated by WordPress, but these addresses may not be recognized.

Comment: It works, I had defined new rules previously using `add_rewrite_rule`. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337924/rewrite-rules-in-multisite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally found the answer 10 minutes after posting this question and spending a couple of hours on it before asking. Simply hook your function to [`post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/)!

```
public function __construct() {
  add_action('post_link', [$this, 'post_links'], 10, 2);
}

public function post_links($link, $post) {
  if ($post->post_type === 'post') {
    return site_url('slug/'. $post->post_name .'-'. $post->ID);
  } else {
    return $link;
  }
}
```